# Jasper Reports Parse XML column-blob

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, jasper-reports

I am using postgresql as database. In db i have one column which contains xml with language codes. I want to parse that xml and get value trough the report language.

`select o.name,o.price from bookdefinations o` This **o.name** contains that xml value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<values>
    <en-us>en value</en-us>
    <es>es value</es>
    <ru>ru value</ru>
    <tr>tr value</tr>
</values>
```

Can i parse this with jasper's expressions or can i parse while selecting from db (i dont have any idea how to get report language in select query and parse xml in select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this directly in postgresql during the select.
PostgreSql has an [XML Type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-xml.html) and various [XML functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-xml.html).

If you take a look at those functions, you'll see the `xpath` function which can be used to extract data from XML types during a select statement.

For a reference to xPath, take a look at the [tutorial from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

Comment: This is ok as i mentioned. But how can i take report language and use for this?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You should be able to extract everything you need directly in postgresql using xPath...

Comment: i will parse xml trought the report language. xml fields are equals to the language codes and i will take only one of these fields.

Comment: Thanks Matt! i digged for your answer and find the solution. I post an edit suggest for your post with sample code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a xmldatasource for jasperreport, you can do a subreport and send the blob to that subreport as an xmldatasource, then you can parse the xml in the subreport and show the content, I'm not sure if you want to show the values or the entire xml, if it is a report I guess you should show the values in a pretty way I mean not as xml, check this link

http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xmldatasource/

Comment: thats looks like what i want but i will use that in table (as field) So if i put subreport as column in datatable i am not sure it can work. i will try this approach.

Comment: The subreport is going to be generated in each row if you have the subreport in the detail area

Comment: jasper didn't accept xml data source as parameter. it requests data source as file. I couldn't find sample about sending it as parameter too. I focused on matt's answer. anyway that was really nice approach, thank you!